# An incomprehensible white square appears when scrolling down

Tags: html, css, clip-path

```css
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette|Roboto");
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    p {
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }

    blockquote {
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 1.5rem;
      font-family: "Courgette", serif;
      font-size: 2rem;
      line-height: 1.25;
      letter-spacing: -0.05rem;
    }
    blockquote:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 6px;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #A9DFBF;
      border-radius: 60px;
    }

    figure {
      display: flex;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .hero {
      position: relative;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .hero:nth-child(1) figure {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/225363/photo-1506260408121-e353d10b87c7.jpg");
    }
    .hero:nth-child(2) figure {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/225363/photo-1506744038136-46273834b3fb.jpg");
    }
    .hero:nth-child(3) figure {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/225363/photo-1523712999610-f77fbcfc3843.jpg");
    }
    .hero:nth-child(4) figure {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/225363/photo-1501785888041-af3ef285b470.jpg");
    }

    .hero-inner {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    }


    .hero__title {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding: 0 1rem;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      color: white;
      font-family: "Courgette", serif;
      font-size: 8vw;
      letter-spacing: -0.125rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .hero__title {
        font-size: 6rem;
      }
    }

    .content {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto 8rem;
      padding: 2rem;
    }
    .content:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: -100px;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 99;
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
              clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
    }

    .content__inner {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 700px;
    }
    .content__inner > * + * {
      margin-top: 1.5rem;
    }
    .content__inner > blockquote {
      margin: 3rem 0;
    }

    .content__title {
      font-family: "Courgette", serif;
      font-size: 3rem;
      line-height: 1.25;
      letter-spacing: -0.125rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      .content__title {
        font-size: 4rem;
      }
    }

    .content__author {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin-bottom: 4rem;
      width: 100%;
      font-family: "Courgette", serif;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      letter-spacing: -0.125rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .content__author:before, .content__author:after {
      content: "";
      flex: 1;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: #A9DFBF;
    }
    .content__author:before {
      margin-right: 1rem;
    }
    .content__author:after {
      margin-left: 1rem;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    <section class="hero">
      <div class="hero-inner" id="section-0">
        <figure></figure>
        <h2 class="hero__title">Explore our world</h2>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="hero">
      <div class="hero-inner" id="section-1">
        <figure></figure>
        <h2 class="hero__title">View all its beauty</h2>
      </div>
    </section> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tze3M.jpg)

Everything works well on the computer, but a square appears on the phone, which spoils everything (The screenshot is posed)
I realized that the problem is in clip-path, but I have no idea how to fix it
I want to fix it, because with this square everything is jerky
Please help fix this

Comment: I can't reproduce this white space when I run your code and simulat a smartphone display.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you play with your sections height in HTML.

Meaning, you can have
`max-height: wtv you want in vh`
`min-height: minimum mandatory height for your view (section in this case)`

I advise you to do:

```
 .hero {
      position: relative;
      width: 100vw;
      min-height: 100vh !important;
    }
```

That way you'll tell the browser that, that view must be mandatorily 100vh and you add `!important` to make sure it definitely happens.

Either way, since it only is affecting your mobile view, you can add that code snippet inside your media query (600px I believe) only. But idk, try it on both and see which one works (or if it works at all heehe)

Best of luck my dude!